# Member group can´t edit comments in CP, but has rights to do so in EE 2.7.0

Tags: control-panel, comments, member-management, administration

I set up a member group called editors. 
Editors can

1. log in to the CP
2. See the link "Pending comments" in the box "Modify or delete".

When an Editor clicks on this link he´ll get a message, saying, that he has no rights to visit the comments section in order to moderate comments. But they should have those rights and I have set up the member group to refelct that.

I set the member group permissions as such:

**Comment Posting Privileges**

Can submit comments Yes
Exclude member from comment moderation No

**Control Panel Access Preferences**

Can access the control panel?    Yes
Can access CONTENT section   Yes
Can access CONTENT: Publish  Yes
Can access CONTENT: Edit     Yes
Can access CONTENT: File Manager Yes

**Comment Administration**

Can Moderate Comments   Yes
Can view comments in channel entries authored by others Yes
Can edit comments in their own channel entries  Yes
Can delete comments in their own channel entries    Yes
Can edit comments in ANY channel entries    Yes
Can delete comments in ANY channel entries  Yes

**Module Access Privileges Preferences**

Can access module:  Comment Yes

To me this looks all good. I also included the Editors in the PUBLISH page multi-author list?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need these...

**Control Panel Access Preferences**

- Can access ADD-ONS section: Yes
- Can access ADD-ONS: Modules: Yes